# textbox not updating its value from viewmodel

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I have a command which sends text when the send button is clicked. The binding is set to two way and the updatesource trigger to propertychanged. but the value of the textbox doesnt change to string.empty which is included in the sendCommand,  even though the command was able to take the updated textbox value for a new message.

```
public class BuddyChatViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string chat;
    public string Chat
    {
        get { return chat; }
        set
        {
            chat = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }        

    public RelayCommand sendChatCommand { get; private set; }
    string username = "";
    string buddy = "";
    UriStrings url = new UriStrings();
    BuddiesHomeModel buddiesList = new BuddiesHomeModel();
    HttpService http = new HttpService();
    StorageService store = new StorageService();
    string response = "";

    BuddyChatModel buddyChat = new BuddyChatModel();
    List<BuddyChat2Datum> buddychatList = new List<BuddyChat2Datum>();
    BuddyChat2Datum tempDatum = new BuddyChat2Datum();
    private ObservableCollection<BuddyChat2Datum> buddyChatOC = new ObservableCollection<BuddyChat2Datum>();
    public ObservableCollection<BuddyChat2Datum> BuddyChatOC
    {
        get { return buddyChatOC; }
        set
        {
            buddyChatOC = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private async void sendChatExecute()
    {            
        int i = 0;
        string s = url.buddychatText(username, buddy, chat);
        chat = "";
        response = await http.GetAsync(s);            
        buddyChat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuddyChatModel>(response);
        buddychatList.Clear();
        for (i = 0; i < buddyChat.data.Count; i++)
        {
            tempDatum.conversation = buddyChat.data[i].conversation;
            tempDatum.datetime = buddyChat.data[i].datetime;
            tempDatum.from = buddyChat.data[i].from;
            tempDatum.to = buddyChat.data[i].to;
            if (tempDatum.from == username)
                tempDatum.isLeft = false;
            else
                tempDatum.isLeft = true;
            buddychatList.Add(tempDatum);
            tempDatum = new BuddyChat2Datum();
        }
        BuddyChatOC.Clear();
        for (i = 0; i < buddychatList.Count; i++)
        {
            BuddyChatOC.Add(buddychatList[i]);
        }
        Navigate<BuddyChatViewModel>(buddychatList);
    }



    #region State Management

    public override void LoadState(object navParameter, Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        sendChatCommand = new RelayCommand(sendChatExecute);
        int i = 0;
        base.LoadState(navParameter, state);
        BuddyChatOC.Clear();
        // load test items again; in production this would retrieve the live item by id or get it from a local data cache
        List<BuddyChat2Datum> buddychatList = (List<BuddyChat2Datum>)navParameter;
        //var mes = new MessageDialog(buddychatList.Count.ToString());
        //await mes.ShowAsync();
        for(i=0;i<buddychatList.Count;i++)
        {
            BuddyChatOC.Add(buddychatList[i]);
        }
        username = buddychatList[i-1].username;
        buddy = buddychatList[i-1].buddy;          
    }


    public override void SaveState(Dictionary<string, object> state)
    {
        base.SaveState(state);

    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

xaml code:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="chatList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding BuddyChatOC}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ChatSelector}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListView>
        <RelativePanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,10,5,10">
            <TextBox x:Name="sendtext" Margin="0,0,2,0" Text="{Binding Chat, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"  RelativePanel.LeftOf="sendtextbutton"/>
            <Button x:Name="sendtextbutton" Content="Send" Command="{Binding sendChatCommand}"  RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" >                    
            </Button>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Have to implement `INotofyPropertyChanged`

Comment: in BuddyChatOC setter you should have RaisePropertyChanged("BuddyChatOC");

Comment: the problem is not with the buddychatoc.. the listview is been updated correctly.. the problem is with the "Chat" string which was the binding property of textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** in **BuddyChatViewModel**.

```
public class BuddyChatViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, BaseViewModel
{
private string chat;
public string Chat
{
    get { return chat; }
    set
    {
        chat = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Chat");
    }
}   


//INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVVMLight (and from how this question is tagged I assume you do), you need to specify changed property name in RaisePropertyChanged call.

That should work in your case:

```
public string Chat
    {
        get { return chat; }
        set
        {
            chat = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Chat);
        }
    }
```